# perl : find nearest smaller number for each element in array

Tags: arrays, perl

wants to generate array which is nearest smaller number for each element in an array.(-1 if the element is 0)

example

Input array: 8 2 4 5 1 6 0 3 2

Output array: 2 1 2 1 0 0 -1 0 0

Comment: Is it your home work? Okay. What have you tried so far.?

Comment: Now explain how you get that output from that input.  "Nearest" and "small" are not exact terms

Comment: @ysth for example if we take 4 in this list. we need to check nearest small number than 4. 1 is far away than 2.

Comment: @mkHun its asked in interview. i tried multiple ways but could not find the solution.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. How do you get those output numbers?

Comment: @melpomene: for each number, they want the nearest smaller number (and the smaller of the two if equally distant)

Comment: @ysth But for 8, the next smallest number is 6. How do you get 2?

Comment: @melpomeme "nearest smaller number", nearest in distance, not smallness

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach doesn't seem like a bad idea here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'min';

my @in = qw/8 2 4 5 1 6 0 3 2/;

my @out;

for my $index (0..$#in) {
    for my $offset (1..$#in) {
        my $least = min(
            $index-$offset >= 0 ? $in[$index-$offset] : (),
            $index+$offset <= $#in ? $in[$index+$offset] : ()
        );

        if ( ! defined $least ) {
            push @out, -1;
            last;
        }
        elsif ( $least < $in[$index]) {
            push @out, $least;
            last;
        }
    }
}

print "@out\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

C# Code to get nearest smaller element in a array

```
        Console.WriteLine("How many numbers you want in your array? ");
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] myArray = new int[length];
        int[] resultArray = new int[length];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter " + length + " numbers for your array..");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length ; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
            int k = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.Length; j++) {
                if (myArray[i] > myArray[j] && (k == -1 || ((i - Array.IndexOf<int>(myArray, k) >= Math.Abs(i - j) ) && k > myArray[j] )))
                {
                    k = myArray[j];
                }
            }
            resultArray[i] = k;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Desired Output: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resultArray[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```